Raycast hits random object
i'm making a game in Unity and i found problem that my raycast points at object but collides with other object called "mm", which is a wall and isn't even near raycast and not points at it.
I want it to not collide with the wall as it ruins whole game up.

you need to share your code, please read [ask], [mcve] to improve your question

In Physics.Raycast documentation as well as in Physics2D.Raycast documentation you can see that it has origin, direction, distance and layerMask parameters.

origin is where your raycast starts from
direction is where your raycast aims
distance is how long your raycast is
layerMask is used to exclude some objects from processing

Use the combination of these parameters to control your raycast.
Also read through the documentation carefully. There might be other helpful overloads of Raycast methods, like the one with ContactFilter2D contactFilter for Physics2D.Raycast.
